# While Loop issue (Java)

Tags: java, while-loop, numberformatexception

I'm trying to make a while loop that prompts the user to re-enter data if they use an invalid entry. In my program I'm asking the user to input a number(0-3), so if they enter anything other than that I want an error message to pop up, asking them to re-enter their data. I don't  know what I'm doing wrong in my loop. No matter what I enter I always get the error message.

```
String itemChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, itemList);
    itemChoiceNum = Integer.parseInt(itemChoice);

    //test to make sure the input is valid
    while (itemChoiceNum != 0 || itemChoiceNum != 1 || itemChoiceNum != 2 || itemChoiceNum != 3) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry that's not a valid choice. Please start again.");
        itemChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, itemList);
    }
```

NumberFormatException

```
    while (itemChoiceNum != 0 && itemChoiceNum != 1 && itemChoiceNum != 2 && itemChoiceNum != 3) {
        try {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry that's not a valid choice. Please start again.");
                                        itemChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, itemList);
                                        itemChoiceNum = Integer.parseInt(itemChoice);
        }

        catch (NumberFormatException itemChoiceNum ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry that's not a valid choice. Please start again.");
        }
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "f"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at VendingClass.displayVend(VendingClass.java:82)
    at VendingMachineDemo.main(VendingMachineDemo.java:12)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect.  It's always true that the choice isn't 0 *or* it isn't 1 *or* it isn't 2; you want "and" with the `&&` operator.

```
while (itemChoiceNum != 0 && itemChoiceNum != 1 && itemChoiceNum != 2 && itemChoiceNum != 4) {
```

Comment: Follow up, is there a way to also show the error message if the user inputs a string? When I put in a string the program crashes.

Comment: Catch the `NumberFormatException` that `Integer.parseInt` throws and show the user the message dialog with an appropriate error message.

Comment: Am I doing it right? I updated my question with what I added.

Comment: It still crashes when I put in a letter. I added the error to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use  should  `&&` instead `||` in the while condition.As of now it always returns True.